# Opening uploaded file with java

Tags: java, ftp

Hy. I have a java code that uploads files trough ftp on a server.The xml file of my project allows all types of files to be uploaded but when i upload certain files like PNG format for example it transfers it but when i try to open the file on the server it doesn't work.

```
 try
    {
        if (!ftp.login(username, password))
        {
            ftp.logout();
            error = true;
            break __main;
        }

        System.out.println("Remote system is " + ftp.getSystemName());

        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: Post your code! Do you upload the PNG file in Binary mode?

Comment: yes i uploaded it in Binary mode and it worked for png but now  gif is giving me some trouble

Comment: as for the code i used it is already on stackoverflow...if you insist i can show you the code...

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are transferring files in TEXT mode. For text files this is fine (in fact preferred) But for binary files like PNG it will corrupt them.

Try sending the PNG in BINARY mode.

Comment: when i try for a format like jpg it work fine....i'll try what you suggested...thank you

Comment: JPG can have the same problem. Its not guaranteed to corrupt the files. ;)

Comment: it worked but for gif type image it only show part of the image the rest is black

Comment: I assume you are send the GIF as binary. Can you check the length is the same?

Comment: yes as binary...it is almost the same on the PC it has 318kb on the server it has 325kb...

Comment: If its not exactly the same number of bytes, the file has been corrupted. This sort of change of size would be expected for a text transfer.

Comment: yet i got it on a gif image....

Comment: So it likely that you are not transferring the file as binary after all. ;)

Comment: i posted a part of the code...

Comment: as you can see it is set to binary mode....:-<

Comment: Can you delete the GIF file and transfer it again?

Comment: that's it I've done it.....the problem was that after i was checking to see if the file was ok with the view option provided by filezilla the image was bad but when i downloaded it to my pc it's ok so the problem was filezilla .Thank you for your patience